# Water not coming out in fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am doing a practice project but in this water is not coming out of it. can you tell me what's wrong in it?

Here's the file: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your resolution. It is too low for your tiny little inflow.

You could either make your inflow bigger or did what i did: change the resolution to 100 and bake again.

Then it works.

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you bro ;)

Comment: you are welcome